# Automatic E-Mail to Admin when Database is Updated

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

Is there a way I can configure automatic e-mails to be sent when new data is added to a MySQL database. Preferably in PHP.

The idea is that when new information is submitted to the DB an e-mail is automatically generated containing the new information with a link to view the information online and sent to a pre-configured e-mail address.

The purpose of this is for a leave booking system. Colleagues will be able to submit dates and times of leave and the team manager is automatically informed as and when they are added or changed.

I have tried using Word Press but it is far too clunky and a lot more powerful than I need. I have also noted another couple of questions here on Stack Flow but they have no responses or answers and not strictly the same question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding the command to send an E-Mail will be trivial to insert: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php It's the *rest* of the task that you need to find the right application for if you don't want to write it from scratch... not sure whether the E-Mail requirement is the right way to start from

Comment: do you have an emailing function set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an SMTP service running, you can outfile to the drop directory. If you have high volume, you may result with duplicate file names, but there are ways to avoid that.

Otherwise, you will need to create a UDF.

Here's a sample trigger solution:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER test.autosendfromdrop BEFORE INSERT ON test.emaildrop
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  /* START THE WRITING OF THE EMAIL FILE HERE*/      
  SELECT  concat("To: ",NEW.To),
          concat("From: ",NEW.From),
          concat("Subject: ",NEW.Subject),
          NEW.Body
      INTO OUTFILE 
               "C:\\inetpub\\mailroot\\pickup\\mail.txt" 
          FIELDS TERMINATED by '\r\n' ESCAPED BY '';            
    END;
```

To markup the message body you will need something like this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION `HTMLBody`(Msg varchar(8192)) 
RETURNS varchar(17408) CHARSET latin1 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare tmpMsg varchar(17408);
set tmpMsg = cast(concat(
  'Date: ',date_format(NOW(),'%e %b %Y %H:%i:%S -0600'),'\r\n',
  'MIME-Version: 1.0','\r\n',
  'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;','\r\n',
  ' boundary=\"----=_NextPart_000_0000_01CA4B3F.8C263EE0\"','\r\n',
  'Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message','\r\n',
  'Importance: normal','\r\n',
  'Priority: normal','\r\n','','\r\n','','\r\n',
  'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.','\r\n','','\r\n',
  '------=_NextPart_000_0000_01CA4B3F.8C263EE0','\r\n',
  'Content-Type: text/plain;','\r\n',
  '  charset=\"iso-8859-1\"','\r\n',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit','\r\n','','\r\n','','\r\n',
  Msg,
  '\r\n','','\r\n','','\r\n',
  '------=_NextPart_000_0000_01CA4B3F.8C263EE0','\r\n',
  'Content-Type: text/html','\r\n',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit','\r\n','','\r\n',
  Msg,
  '\r\n','------=_NextPart_000_0000_01CA4B3F.8C263EE0--'
  ) as char);
 RETURN tmpMsg;
 END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might first try the [php mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Whether that's sufficient depends on the application. For example, system admins can update any of my databases through using the dbms's native command-line program. They could also use the GUI utility, or even something like Excel (maybe) to do updates that php won't see at all. If that happens, you won't see any email about those changes.

At least some dbms's can execute an email application from within the database. But that can raise some security issues. (As a rule, my databases don't write to the filesystem except during a backup/dump, and they don't interact with email.) Give some thought to what you want to happen if some administrator updates every row in the table.  (Most often, that administrator will be you.)

Personally, I don't think I'd use email for this. It's something that (IMHO) should only grab an administrator's attention once a day at most. For that, I'd probably first try a web page that shows changes since the administrator's last visit.