# Automatic email to users when database is updated

Tags: mysql, database, email

I would like to know how to automatically send an email to confirm their subscription to the users who sign up. Basically, when a user signs up, it adds a line in a SQL database.

Thank you very much, I hope this is clear.

Comment: I guess this should be implemented in the Program, not in the DB

Comment: Please put some code and specify in which language you are working for email??

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387018/automatic-e-mail-to-admin-when-database-is-updated/11409620#11409620[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387018/automatic-e-mail-to-admin-when-database-is-updated/11409620#11409620

Answer (score 0):

You should do it on your language level.